# Convert numbers from Scientific Notation to text

Tags: excel, vba

I tried so many ways (.numberformats, etc.), I cannot manage to convert those scientific numbers (column [A]) into text, so that the EAN Code is shown properly (column [B]).

I need a VBA solution.

any suggestions?

[image]

edit: **solution** which works for me, but I am not happy with:

```
For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & i).NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A" & i) = Trim(Range("A" & i))
Next i
```

This will directly convert Column [A] into the right format.

Comment: Non VBA solution = Format > Custom > 0

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you. TL;DR: this isn't a code writing service so you'll have to provide your best shot at it and indicate where you're stuck, then someone will help you fix that specific issue.

Comment: Thanks, I know that rule and tried to tell that coding like ".numberformats.etc" won't work. so I did not paste my not working code in here...

Comment: What about using `TEXT`? In `B2` put `=TEXT(A2,"#")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim iRowCount As Integer

iRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("B2:B" & iRowCount).Value = Range("A2:A" & iRowCount).Value
Range("B2:B" & iRowCount).NumberFormat = "0"
```

Comment: Just a note, for large sets of data, it'd be better to declare `iRowCount` as a `long`. `Integer` values have a max of `32,767` whereas `longs` have a max of `2,147,483,647` which will cover the max number of rows in a sheet which is `1,048,576`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub FFF()
    Range("B2").Value = "" & Range("A2").Value
End Sub
```